# How can I create an accessory view for my table cell like this?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, accessoryview

Basically I need two labels. one with a number and other with the constant string letters on next line.Also I need a speech bubble as background for accessory view.I know how to create one label , but no idea about setting two label as accessory view. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a UIView and add all the necessary views to it as its subviews, then make that single view the accessory view of the table view cell:

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
[container addSubview:backgroundImage];
[container addSubview:firstLabel];
[container addSubview:secondLabel];
cell.accessoryView = container;
```

Comment: @Harikrishnan It's easy to say 'not working'. You have to make some effort yourself. Set the frame properly, as per the actual needs, arrange the labels within the container view, bring them to the font in order them to appear, etc. Also, 'aren't displaying properly' is less than informative... Do they suddenly display Mezopotamian handwriting or what?

Comment: Got it.the co-ordinates were incorrect. It's working now. thanks

Answer (score 3):

For that, you need to create one ImageView or UIView and set the image accordingly.

Then you have set the accessory view of the cell like below:

```
cell.accessoryView = <your view>;
```

Hope, you got an idea.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its works fine for me.....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        UILabel  *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 100, 21)];
         UILabel  *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25,42, 100, 21)];
        label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 110)];
        [container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bukkl.png"]]];
        [container addSubview:label1];
        [container addSubview:label2];
        label1.text = @"HIIIIIIII";
        label2.text = @"@@@BBBBBB";
        cell.accessoryView = container;
    }

         return cell;
}
```

If it works well than don't forget to upvote..